# Simpy - service time dependent on length of queue and resources availability

Tags: python, simulation, yield, simpy, event-simulation

I want to modify this code to solve the following problem: Lets say we have two nurses. If both nurses are free then a patient can use both nurses and the treatment time is cut in half. A patient can use both nurses only if there aren't any patients waiting in the queue. If there are two (or more) patients in queue then we take 2 patients off the queue and assign them to each nurse.

```
import simpy
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

# Define arrival and service time distributions
def draw_arrival_time():
    # Use an exponential distribution for arrival times 
    return np.random.exponential(2.0)

def draw_service_time():
    # Use a normal distribution for service times 
    return np.random.normal(5.0, 1.0)

# Arrivals generator function
def patient_generator(env, nurse):
    patient_id = 1

    while True:
        # Create an instance of activity generator
        patient = treatment_activity(env, nurse, patient_id)

        # Run the activity generator for this patient
        env.process(patient)

        # Sample time until next arrival
        next_arrival = draw_arrival_time()

        # Freeze until that time has passed
        yield env.timeout(next_arrival)
        patient_id += 1

def treatment_activity(env, nurse, patient_id):
    # Patient arrival
    time_entered_queue = env.now
    print("Patient", patient_id, "arrived at", time_entered_queue)

    # Request the nurse
    with nurse.request() as req:
        yield req

        # Calculate the time patient left the queue
        time_left_queue = env.now
        print("Patient", patient_id, "started treatment at", time_left_queue)

        # Calculate the waiting time for this patient
        waiting_time = time_left_queue - time_entered_queue

        # Append the waiting time to the waiting_times list
        waiting_times.append(waiting_time)

        # Sample treatment time
        treatment _time = draw_service_time()

        yield env.timeout(treatment_time)

# Set up simulation environment
env = simpy.Environment()

# Set up resources
nurse = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)

# Set up parameter values
waiting_times = []

# Start patient arrivals generator
env.process(patient_generator(env, nurse))

# Run the simulation
env.run(until=90)

# Calculate and print statistics
average_waiting_time = np.mean(waiting_times)
print("Average Waiting Time:", average_waiting_time)
```

I tried using a resource with capacity 2 nurse = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=2) but this didn't work. Then using two nurses with capacity 1 each, but I couldn't keep track of the queue and didn't how to check if both are free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example of a patient grabbing one or two nurses and setting the treatment time base on the nurse resource request queue size and the number of available nurses.

```
"""
Simple simulation of nusrses treating a patient.

If there is only one patient and both nureses are available,
both nurses will treat the patient
with a half the treatment time.

If there is more then one patatient each nurse will take one patient

Programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy

class Patient():
    """
    Patient that needs a nurse,
    has a id for tracking
    """

    last_id = 0

    def __init__(self):
    
        self.__class__.last_id += +1

        self.id = self.__class__.last_id

def treat_patient(env, patient, nurse_resource):
    """
    Main process where a patient:
    waits for a nurse (maybe 2)
    gets treated
    release the nurses
    """

    treat_time = 6

    # wait for nurse
    n_req =nurse_resource.request() 
    yield n_req

    # list of nurses to be released later
    n_reqs = [n_req]

    # chech if patient queue is empty
    if len(nurse_resource.queue ) == 0:
        
        #check if second nurse is available
        if nurse_resource.capacity - nurse_resource.count >= 1:
            # get second nurse and cut treatment time
            n_req_2 = nurse_resource.request()
            yield n_req_2

            n_reqs.append(n_req_2)
            treat_time = treat_time / 2

    # start treatment (note no yield here, just drop and go)
    print(f'{env.now:.1f}: patient {patient.id} is being treated by {len(n_reqs)} nurses')

    yield env.timeout(treat_time)

    # release all the nurses, could be 1 or 2
    for req in n_reqs:
        nurse_resource.release(req)

    print(f'{env.now:.1f}: patient {patient.id} treatment is finished by {len(n_reqs)} nurses')

def gen_patients(env, nurse_resource):
    yield env.timeout(1)
    patient = Patient()
    env.process(treat_patient(env, patient, nurse_resource))
    print(f'{env.now:.1f}: patient {patient.id} has arrived')

    yield env.timeout(1)
    patient = Patient()
    env.process(treat_patient(env, patient, nurse_resource))
    print(f'{env.now:.1f}: patient {patient.id} has arrived')

    yield env.timeout(1)
    patient = Patient()
    env.process(treat_patient(env, patient, nurse_resource))
    print(f'{env.now:.1f}: patient {patient.id} has arrived')

    yield env.timeout(30)
    patient = Patient()
    env.process(treat_patient(env, patient, nurse_resource))
    print(f'{env.now:.1f}: patient {patient.id} has arrived')

    yield env.timeout(1)
    patient = Patient()
    env.process(treat_patient(env, patient, nurse_resource))
    print(f'{env.now:.1f}: patient {patient.id} has arrived')



env = simpy.Environment()
nurse_resource = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=2)
env.process(gen_patients(env, nurse_resource))

env.run(100)
```